# Spawn Images on certain position Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin.forms

Hello Xamarin community!
I just started with Xamarin Forms and wanted to create a simple app, which helps counting on a card game.

The points should be visualized in this image and should look like the following one:
[image: ShouldLookLike]

In the first row there should be a horizontal line every fifth line and on the second line there should be a horizontal line every second line.

Here is how it looks like when i manually add the lines and add a backgroundcolor for visualization:
[image: actuallylookslike]

Here is the View:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Entry Text="{Binding Team1.Name}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Text="150"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding Team2.Name}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Text="129"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

    <Image Source="Schlange.png"
           Aspect="Fill"
           BackgroundColor="#" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
           Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.RowSpan="3" />
    <Image Scale="0.5" BackgroundColor="Gray" Source="Strich1.png"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Image BackgroundColor="Blue" Source="Strich1.png"/>

    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Button BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
    <Label Text="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"></Label>
    <Label Text="-1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"></Label>
    
    <Entry Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6"></Entry>
    <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"></Entry>
    <Button Text="Runde!" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

My Question would be how to spawn Images on certain positions? Is this even possible with a grid? What happens to mobile phones with different resolution?

Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to ask if needed.

Comment: Like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42393/need-to-add-rows-dynamically-in-a-grid)?

Comment: if you want to place elements in specific positions, use an AbsoluteLayout.  Or you might consider just using a Skia canvas

Comment: @Shaw not really :/

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the game rules actually. Are there four players for one game? the long curve line is a fixed background line? And put 1-5 chips (horizontal lines) on each side for the score? If so, it is not to add some row/col dynamically, it is to change the image overlay on the board.

Comment: You should add more detailed information to describe what you want to achieve, the picture you added is not so clear.